# Error : DEP0700 : Registration of the app failed. error 0x80070002: Windows cannot register the package because of an internal error or low memory

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I am using visual studio 2013 to create a window 8.1 store app. When I run simulator. I received error message "Error : DEP0700 : Registration of the app failed. error 0x80070002: Windows cannot register the package because of an internal error or low memory. (0x80073cf6) App1". I have try reinstall it, but still have this error. How do solve it?

Comment: How much RAM and Disk space do you have available?

Comment: disk space: 197 free of 292; ram 4GB. But my windows OS sometime is lagging. Is it RAM got problem?

Comment: Have a look at http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-winapps/error-code-80073cf6/072950ed-8768-4517-bd85-553fd56abd67

Comment: I had this problem and for me it was sqlite studio had open the local database.

Comment: FWIW I had this error, but it was because my solution lived on a SanDisk SD card (D drive). I moved it to the C drive (built-in hard drive) and it built without issue.

Answer (score 3):

problem is "visual studio is not able to delete the application data in local folder"
so when you go in the location C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Packages you will find application data of app installed in your computer
now you need to find your app's applicaion data and delete the folder. folder name is same as the package family name which you can see in your solution.
now again open the solution and rebuild and your app will run. ^_^
Note -> 1. close visual studio and simulator before deleting the folder.
2. make sure that your account is set as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this when I realized my development path was to long, also I disabled my anti virus for the first that I ran the app. This seemed to fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar problem while developing in VS 2015
Its simple, you just have to do is go to:  Build --> Clean Solution
and then Build --> Rebuild Solution. That should solve this error.