# C++ MFC Windows - NVIDIA 3D Active Shutter API Alternative

Tags: c++, mfc, direct3d, stereo-3d, nvapi

I was handed a NVIDIA Active Shutter 3D program that needs to be converted to not be dependent on NVIDIA GPU's. I've never handled graphics API's and am having a hard time finding an alternative API that will work with what I have.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Basically I just need the existing code to work on a Samsung Active Shutter HDTV without using NVIDIA anything.

Existing program is c++ mfc windows standalone and uses NVAPI (dx9 VS2008 project) and a completely custom engine that I didn't code.

Open to any and all reasonable suggestions. I'm not a coding veteran so please try to keep it as beginner friendly as possible. I normally do c# so i'm a bit out of my element with this c++ stuff.

Thanks ahead of time for the help!

Comment: just ran across the following but not sure if it would work.....: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Ch9Live/Channel-9-Live-at-BUILD-2012/Introduction-to-DirectX-3D-D3D-

Comment: You could switch to DirectX if that does the job for you. As for the term beginner friendly, good luck. Is the custom engine based on the NVAPI too or not ? If not, you could maybe handle this in some way. Without more specific information this is too vague.

Comment: The custom engine uses NVAPI for handling stereoscopic active shutter 3D. Its the NVAPI code I need to replace with something else

Comment: What specifics do you need?

Answer (score 0):

In Direct3D there is no vendor-independent way to enable active stereo until **Direct3D 11.1**. Prior to 11.1, you have no choice but to use the AMD and NVIDIA specific non-standard methods.

Also note that Direct3D 9 and Direct3D 11.1 are very different APIs, and Direct3D 11.1 stereoscopy requires Windows 8 or later. Porting effort may or  may not be substantial.

If you're interested in Direct3D stereoscopy you can start at this MSDN [sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Direct3D-111-Simple-Stereo-9b2b61aa).

Comment: that looks good but I can't get the sample to compile. something about cannot register the app error....  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19331894/error-dep0700-registration-of-the-app-failed-error-0x80070002-windows-cann       tried the solutions mentioned in the linked post but no go. ideas?